# Lambda filter a list of dictionaries Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I started programming with python a little while ago I have a doubt with dictionary

I have this array and I already have a method that gets an id array, I tried with lambda to create a filtered list,
My question is if in addition to the filtered list I can leave in the list only the necessary attributes as the example

example:

```
 ages = [{'employedId': 1, 'age': 22},
         {'employedId': 2, 'age': 32},
         {'employedId': 3, 'age': 17},
         {'employedId': 4, 'age': 53},
         {'employedId': 5, 'age': 32},
         {'employedId': 6, 'age': 22}
         ]
list_filtred = list(filter(lambda tag: tag['age'] == 22, ages))
```

**python output**

```
[{'employedId': 1, 'age': 22}, 
 {'employedId': 6, 'age': 22}]
```

Can I create a lambda  filtering method to have such an output or do I have to work on the array to create a new values ​​list?

**expected output**

```
[1,6]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a list comprehension to access the value corresponding to the `'employedId'` key after you've used the `'age'` for filtering.

```
>>> [tag['employedId'] for tag in ages if tag['age'] == 22]
[1, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know it would be possible like this

Answer (score 2):

The `filter` function on its own won't do this, but you can do this using a functional, declarative style (rather than imperative).

For example, to extract all the people whose age is 22

```py
list_filtered = list(filter(lambda tag: tag['age']==22, ages))
```

Lambda functions are powerful tools; you can construct a variety of conditions.

To get the array in the format you want, try the `map` function which uses similar principles but instead of filtering an array it applies the result of the function to each item in the array.

```py
list_filtered = list(map(lambda x: x['employedId'], ages))
```

Comment: Careful, `map` does not return a `list`, but an iterator

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative leveraging your existing `list` statement, you could add a `map` statement that grabs the `employedId` key:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

list(map(itemgetter('employedId'), filter(lambda tag: tag['age'] == 22, ages)))
[1, 6]
```

Otherwise, I think @CoryKramer's answer is a bit more readable